# What are you using to get GPS data on windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, gps

I cannot find a solution that works on all my devices. I need a library that will work on windows mobile 6 and 6.5. I can get the sdk sample to work on my HTC HD2 but it will not work on the HTC Diamond(Fuze)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [Intermediate Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx). this works well for me for all kinds of mobile phones using windows mobile (up to 6.5)

Comment: GPSID (GPS Intermediate Driver) should work starting from Windows Mobile 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Download [Windows Mobile 6 SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=87437) or  [Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=183070) and install it.

In folder C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\Samples\Common\ you can find GPS code samples.

Answer (score 0):

GPS.NET [v2.0](http://gps2.codeplex.com/) or [v3.0](http://gps3.codeplex.com/) should work with your devices, if you're looking for a managed code library.